# Get individual elements from a json

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a json response that looks like so:

```
{
    "Matches":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 1, "score": 254},
                {"id": 2, "score": 253}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 1, "score": 330},
                {"id": 3, "score": 331}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 1, "score": 220},
                {"id": 4, "score": 220}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 1, "score": 264},
                {"id": 5, "score": 189}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 2, "score": 240},
                {"id": 3, "score": 200}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 2, "score": 330},
                {"id": 4, "score": 331}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 2, "score": 320},
                {"id": 5, "score": 220}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 3, "score": 320},
                {"id": 4, "score": 300}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 3, "score": 280},
                {"id": 5, "score": 300}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "Teams": [
                {"id": 4, "score": 180},
                {"id": 5, "score": 180}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the struct I have for the above response:

```
struct Matches: Codable {
    let matches: [Match]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case matches = "Matches"
    }
}

// MARK: - Match
struct Match: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let teams: [Team]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case teams = "Teams"
    }
}

// MARK: - Team
struct Team: Codable {
    let id, score: Int
}
```

And this is how I'm making the api call to get the data:

```
fileprivate func getMatches() {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "URL HERE")!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Matches.self, from: data)

        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

But what I'm not able to figure out is how I can compare the scores of 2 id's within the `Teams` in the `json` response and say which id is greater and also the count of each id's..

Comment: I don't get the question. What's the problem? You don't know how to find a specific Team by id?

Comment: Do you need to sum all scores and compare?

Comment: yes @Wojciech Kulik and also the id and score within each team

Comment: No @MojtabaHosseini For eg., for the 1st team array I want to compare if 253 and 254 and since 254 is greater say that id:1 has won…and similarely the count of won and losses for others also...

Comment: I think you should consider adding a helper function that takes this data and turns it into a better data model because the current struct is not very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matches of team 1:

```
let team1 = res.matches.filter {$0.teams.contains { $0.id == 1 }}
```

Find the winner of each match, use this extension:

```
extension Match {
    var winnerTeam: Team {
        return teams.sorted { $0.score > $1.score }.first!
    }
}
```

for example the array of winners would be like:

```
let winners = res.matches.map { $0.winnerTeam }
```

Similarly for finding looser teams:

```
extension Match {
    var looserTeam: Team {
        return teams.sorted { $0.score > $1.score }.last!
    }
}
```

For counting winner teams by id:

```
func scoresOfWinners() -> [Int: Int] {
    var scores = [Int: Int]()
    for team in winners {
        scores[team.id] = (scores[team.id] ?? 0) + 1
    }
    return scores
}
```

it will return a list of id: win count.

Remember if you want to handle `tie` situation, you should guard before picking winner or looser like this:

```
var winnerTeam: Team? {
    guard teams.first!.score != teams.last!.score else { return nil }
    return teams.sorted { $0.score > $1.score }.first!
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mojtaba Hosseini…But if the scores are equal as in the case of score 220, no id would be a winner. How do we achieve that..?

Comment: You should filter out the ties from the winners then.